# `>` character doesn't display bolded in email client

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm trying to get a HTML design in an email, and needed to get `>` in bold. When the email is viewed in Outlook Web, this doesn't work. But if I use a different character (for example: `a`) other than `>`, this style would work.
I tried to get `>` character bold as shown in the below code:

```
<span style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 20px;">
                                                                                            >
                                                                                                </span>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using <strong>&gt;</strong>

Comment: Replace your ">" to this "&gt;"

Comment: <b> is old, stay with span and font weight strong. And using &gt; You will not go wrong

Answer (score 0):

`>` is a reserved character in HTML, as a crucial component for forming `<html>` `<tags>`.

Try using the escaped form, `&gt;`, instead, and replace `font-weight: bolder` with `bold`.

---

### Demo Snippet:

```html
<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;">&gt;</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of email client don't understand inline style. so instead of this you can use:

```
<span style="font-size: 20px;"><b>&gt;</b></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

">" can be printed in bold by

```
<b>&gt;</b>
```

In the code`&gt;` stands for ">"

Answer (score 0):

In Newsletters and mail use basic HTML when you can, it's always safer, so for this use:

```
<b>&gt;</b>
```